# Android database useing multiple like statements

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

I am making a `search` function and I need to search using two inputs:

1. the category id (CID) it is a string that is contained (or not) in KEY_P_CAT_LIST (it cant be done with = as it usually isn't equal)
2. the search text input (input)

I need to check if the category and the input text is contained in the db record and return it in a cursor if so.

coloane is correctly defined as a `[]` String and is not the problem.

My atempt:

`db.query(true, P_TABLE, coloane,KEY_P_CAT_LIST + " LIKE " + " AND " +CID + " LIKE", new String[] {"%"+CID+"%", "%"+input+"%"}, null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.query(true, P_TABLE, coloane,KEY_P_CAT_LIST + " LIKE ?" + " AND " +CID + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%"+CID+"%", "%"+input+"%"}, null, null, null, null);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: It is not crashing anymore but gives no results when I give it an input, but if the input is empty it works but shows all products in the category

Comment: actually it works, I had to add KEY_P_NAME instead of CID
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Like" is case sensitive in SQLite. so i hope you have checked the input string and db data has no differences Case wise.

Comment: when it compares the input to the database value it is not case sensitive: if I add aqua and the value is Aqua it still works.
I will have to take in consideration multiple inputs such as "laptop asus" and search for each word separately then sort result by relevance but I'm just making a demo so that's for a later time.